# change return type of the superclass method

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

Having a scala class

```
class JobsHistory extends mutable.HashSet[JobInstance] {

      /**
       * Filter only Map Reduce Jobs
       * @return
       */
      implicit def onlyMapReduce = this.filter((job) => job.mapTasksCount > 0 && job.reduceTasksCount > 0)

      /**
       * Filter only jobs with successful status
       * @return
       */
      implicit def onlySucceeded = this.filter((job) => job.status == "SUCCEEDED")
    }
```

I would like to be able to do type of a call

```
instances.onlyMapReduce.onlySucceeded
```

where `instances` is a `JobsHistory` type. The problem is that I call a filter which is coming from superclass and returns `HashSet` rather than `JobsHistory`, how can I ensure proper return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just adding those methods to a `Set` using Pimp My Library pattern.

```
case class JobInstance(status: String, mapTasksCount: Int, reduceTasksCount: Int)

implicit class JobHistory(val jobs: Set[JobInstance]) extends AnyVal {
  def onlyMapReduce = jobs.filter((job) => job.mapTasksCount > 0 && job.reduceTasksCount > 0)

  def onlySucceeded = jobs.filter(_.status == "SUCCEEDED")
}

val set = Set(JobInstance("SUCCEEDED", 3, 3), JobInstance("SUCCEEDED", 0, 3), JobInstance("Failed", 3, 3))

set.onlyMapReduce.onlySucceeded
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[JobInstance] = Set(JobInstance(SUCCEEDED,3,3))
```

It would work the same with mutable Set as `filter` returns a new set no matter if it's mutable or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good case to prefer composition over inheritance.

```
case class JobHistory(jobs: Set[JobInstance]) {
  def onlyMapReduce = copy(jobs = jobs filter (job => 
    job.mapTasksCount > 0 && job.reduceTasksCount > 0
  ))

  def onlySucceeded = copy(jobs = jobs filter (job => job.status == "SUCCEEDED"))
}
```

Note that I have replaced `mutable.HashSet` by `immutable.Set`.